# Warning: `pkgname` is neither a file nor directory, skipping

Tags: r, command-prompt

I try to execute the code  `R CMD check pkgname`  but its result is

```
C:\Users\username>R CMD check pkgname
Warning: 'pkgname' is neither a file nor directory, skipping
```

I also execute the following, but it does not go well.

```
C:\Users\username>R CMD Rd2pdf pkgname
Converting Rd files to LaTeX ...
  pkgname
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'pkgname': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

------------My package name is BayesianAAAA--------------------------------

```
C:\Users\username>R CMD check BayesianAAAA
Warning: 'BayesianAAAA' is neither a file nor directory, skipping


C:\Users\username>R CMD Rd2pdf BayesianAAAA
Converting Rd files to LaTeX ...
  BayesianAAAA
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'BayesianAAAA': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

-----------Open command prompt on my package directory--------------------------------

By [shift] + right click, I open command prompt on my package and running the above code. However the result is same as previous one.

```
C:\Users\usename\Desktop\BayesianAAAA>R CMD Rd2pdf BayesianAAAA
Converting Rd files to LaTeX ...
  BayesianAAAA
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'BayesianAAAA': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

--------- Writing by path of my pkg directory, **the code goes well !! Great !!**------------------

```
C:\Users\usename>R CMD Rd2pdf C:\Users\usename\Desktop\BayesianFROC
Hmm ... looks like a package
Converting Rd files to LaTeX ...
Creating pdf output from LaTeX ...
sed: not found
sed: not found
kpsewhich: not found
cat: not found
Warning: running command '"C:\w32tex\bin\texi2dvi.exe"  --pdf "Rd2.tex" ' had status 1
Saving output to 'BayesianAAAA.pdf' ...
Done
'BayesianAAAA.pdf' not found
Warning: running command 'open BayesianAAAA.pdf' had status 34
```

Comment: Is your package called `pkgname`? I think you are supposed to replace `pkgname` with the name of a package you want to check.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I had changed pkgname to my package name, such as BayesianAAAA. So, the above code and outputs, I changed to pkgname.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate you want to make the question general. You could try changeing the command promt directory (using `cd`) to the parent folder of your package, or use the full file path instead.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I open the command prompt on my package, and running the same code, but the result is same.

Comment: Sorry, from now on I can reply after 14 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `R CMD check` needs to be a `.tar.gz` filename or a directory name.  Since your current working directory was `C:\Users\usename\Desktop\BayesianAAAA` the directory name to use would be `.`, not `BayesianAAAA`.  If you want

```
R CMD check BayesianAAAA
```

to work, your working directory needs to be `C:\Users\usename\Desktop`.  Alternatively, you should be able to use

```
R CMD check C:/Users/usename/Desktop/BayesianAAA
```

but if `usename` has spaces in it, this probably won't work without some kind of quoting around the path.

BTW, this is a lot easier if you use RStudio:  you set up your package as a project, then just click on `Check` in the `Build` tab.

Comment: Thank you, the code has run on a command prompt !! The code's result has error, and not create the pdf file, but tex file named Rd2.tex is created. So, I open Rd2.tex by Texworks, it says that "  `! LaTeX Error: File `Rd.sty' not found.`
  " . Anyway, the  code goes well. I appreciate @user2554330.

Comment: Note that I used Rstudio and also attempt to create the pdf manual as @user2554330, however, by clicking it create a file  pkgname.Rcheck  without a pdf manual.

Comment: Don't use `check` to create the manual, use `check` to check the package.  I don't know if RStudio has a button to build the manual.  I'd use `R CMD Rd2pdf BayesianAAA` from the command line if I wanted it.  (Same rules for current directory as for `R CMD check`.)

Comment: Thank you for kind reply, and I try the code, `R CMD Rd2pdf `. To tell the truth I asked this question for `R CMD Rd2pdf` not `R CMD check` which endowed in Rstudio . However the error occurs described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750305/in-r-r-cmd-rd2pdf-does-not-create-pdf-manual.